# Selenium work with python2 but not with python3

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium with `python3`. I made a tiny script to simply open a firefox browser, which leads to `google.ch` afterwards. 
Now my problem is that this works fine with `python2`, but if I try to run the script with `python3`, firefox browser opens, but it doesn't open `google.ch`.

I really want to do the whole thing with `python3`.. Anyone an idea what the problem could be?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')

driver.get("https://google.ch")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)sudo rm
```

*Note: I installed selenium with `pip3`*

**Error Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python_projects/SitzwacheTool/read.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

Comment: what si the error your getting?

Comment: no error. just a normal, empty browser window.

Comment: wait, after couple minutes of waiting i get a connection refused

Comment: can you add the exact error message to the question?

Comment: Version difference of selenium perhaps? What is ``selenium.__version__`` in python 2 vs python 3?

Comment: @codeape python2.7.13 = version 2.53.1 and python3.5.3 = version 3.14.1

Comment: @Navarasu i updated the question. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Can you try updating the firefox browser version and check? Also are u running in xvfb ?

Comment: OK so the version difference could explain what you're seeing. To check if this indeed is the case I suggest you install ``pip install selenium==2.53.1`` in the python 3 environment as well.

Comment: @codeape doesn't change anything, sadly

Comment: @Navarasu xvfb is for hidden browserwindow right? If that's so, no i am not running xvfb although i downloaded it